# How to get fluent api mapped entity table name EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm having problems getting the mapped table name when using fluent api. When you use data annotations it's easy because you can use the TableAttribute in order to get the table name from an specific entity, but when I use fluent api I can't find a way to do that.

I need it because I'm implementing an audit trail overriding the SaveChanges on the dbContext.

Thanks

Comment: Rowan Miller has written about getting the complete mapping information from the metadataworkspace: [link](http://romiller.com/2013/09/24/ef-code-first-mapping-between-types-tables/).

Comment: Exactly I uses that:) I will answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

In order to get information about the Entity when using Fluent API I did this:

```
// get the actual entity Set
// DataSpace.SSpace = Storage part of the model has info about the shape of our tables
var entitySet = workspace.GetItems<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityContainer>(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.SSpace)
                .SelectMany(e => e.EntitySets).ToList().Where(a => a.Name == entityTypeName).FirstOrDefault();
```

And finally:

```
// Get table name
string tableName = entitySet.Table;
```

Hope this can help others!